Hybrid Scrolling with Locomotive Library (Frontend Beginner)
For my Portfolio website, I would like to enable hybrid scrolling with the Locomotive Scroll Library. Apparently, I am not aware of the correct implementation and I am still a beginner (coming from Product Design, just recently learned development) – so please be nice to me and try to explain it for beginners :)
Could you help me to find the right way to use Locomotive Scroll for my request?
In my Replit it works partly as I want it to:
https://replit.com/@loonxdesign/Locomotive-Horizontal-Scroll-Test
You can also see the code here:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Locomotive Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Content first">
            <h1>Hey</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    <div class="Content second">
        <h2>What's up?</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Content third">
        <h1>Good</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Content four">
        <h2>And you!</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div data-scroll-container>
        <div class="wrap" data-scroll-section>
            <div class="Content first">
              <h1>Hey</h1>
             <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Content second">
                <h2>What's up?</h2>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Content third">
                <h1>Good</h1>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Content four">
                <h2>And you!</h2>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Content that should scroll vertically again
    <div class="Content first">
        <h1>Hey</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Content second">
        <h2>What's up?</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Content third">
        <h1>Good</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Content four">
        <h2>And you!</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@4.1.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Grifinito L";
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 400vw;
}

.Content {
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.first{
  background-color:red;
}
.second{
  background-color:orange;
}
.third{
  background-color:green;
}
.four{
  background-color:blue;
}

const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
    smooth: true,
    direction: 'horizontal'
});

The commented-out part in the HTML file should scroll vertically again after horizontal scrolling. However, if I switch this part on, the horizontal scrolling does not work at all and instead everything is scrolled vertically, so I have hidden the part for the time being so that you can understand my approach with Locomotive.
I also tried to use this also for my website, but horizontal scrolling only works partially there too. Here I want everything to scroll vertically except for the part inside the home-section--wrapper:
https://github.com/loonxdesign/Original-Portfolio
I need a solution for hybrid scrolling without the user having to change their scrolling behaviour with the mouse (i.e. the user scrolls vertically as normal the whole time, although a certain part scrolls horizontally).
